# Slow boot time due to firmware delay

Tags: linux, boot, firmware

A couple days ago I installed Linux Mint Cinnamon GUI as a third party package. I'm running linux-4.15.0-15-generic.

My systemd-analyze looks like this.

`Startup finished in 42.849s (firmware) + 5.076s (loader) + 6.438s  (kernel) + 18.856s (userspace) = 1min 13.220s`

I don't understand why the firmware takes nearly 40 seconds to load. I guess the firmware needs to take as less time as possible.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT: I'm ready to provide hardware specs if asked.